Why MSVC std::exponential_distribution::max() returns inf?
Why the following code prints inf with the latest MSVC++ ?
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    
    std::exponential_distribution<double> d(1);

    std::cout << "max = " << d.max() << std::endl << std::endl;
}

No such issue with Clang (not sure how to get output for gcc – see the same demo).
I see in the std::exponential_distribution:

Some implementations may occasionally return infinity if RealType is float. This is LWG issue 2524.

But default type is double and the same issue occurs if I explicitly put double or long double for the std::exponential_distribution.
Is this a bug only in max() method or should I really care if MSVC could generate inf even for double type? (Due to random nature of the method writing a test for this is next to impossible).
I see some suspicious things at the C++ exponential_distribution occasionally returns inf where 0 is expected:

In the answer it is stated that changing type to double only reduces the chance of the problem;
In the comment from author under his question it is stated that switching to double fixed the issue.

Should I get this like “since now it become rarer, the author of the question become happy getting time-bomb for his code which will cause inf unexpectedly and quite rare = hard to find and debug”?
If so, what is the use of this distribution if I could get inf as a result which most likely will cause overflows, exceptions, wrong calculations and, eventually, undefined behavior?
Should I check for std::isinf() after each generation?

According to mathematical spec, the range is [λ,∞). So INF should be valid as max() and since long double eventually trims real numbers above certain value, INF should be valid as a rare outcome - representing anything larger than representable. IMHO, this should be the expected behavior. You can refine it for personal use. Define a distro encapsulating expo, clamping above certain threshold and having the threshold as its max:assert(my_clamped_expo_distro{L, M}.max()==M);

Re: "Is this a bug only in max() method" -- it's not a bug. The non-standard text you cited mentions that this is LWG issue 2524, which means that it's something that the Library Working Group is looking at.

@Red.Wave, I am a little bit lost here. If returning inf is expected behavior, what is the purpose of the note "Some implementations may occasionally return infinity if RealType is float. This is LWG issue 2524." and why is it the issue? With you (correct) reasoning any type can return inf and there is no any value in this note.

@PeteBecker, if this is not a bug, what the meaning of this note in this document?

@DamirTenishev — it means that somebody said it was a bug. That doesn’t make it one. That document is not the C++ Standard.

STD doesn't always spec the details, until some confusing expressions need clarification. From a math point of view, IEEE and other representation of floating point numbers cnnot hold even a limited range of real numbers. Eventually they can only hold a discreet set of values. So, PDF and RNG are essentially discreet valued functions. Allowing numeric_limits::infinity as valid output, stretchs the range to the fullest. You can limit your RNG to numeric_limits::max at any time; the standard utility is the least restrictive. Random numbers are expensive; one extra branch won't cost much.

std::exponential_distribution<RealType>::max() in Microsoft C++ Standard Library  is implemented to return numeric_limits<result_type>::infinity()
result_type(max)() const noexcept /* strengthened */ { // get largest possible result
    return numeric_limits<result_type>::infinity();
}

If it's needed, std::isinf() should be used.
rand.dist.pois.exp#1

An exponential_distribution random number distribution produces random numbers x > 0 distributed according to the probability density function in Formula 29.9.


The max value is not specified. Hence, this is implementation details.
From the math point of view, inf is a correct answer although its occurrence probability is 0.
What you refer, is not related to std::exponential_distribution<RealType>::max()

Some implementations may occasionally return infinity if RealType is float. This is LWG issue 2524.

